# Initialize writable svelte store from sapper preload

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I want to do something like this:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload() {
        const topicRes = await this.fetch(`topics/all.json`).catch((error) => {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error)
        });
        const serverTopics = await topicRes.json();
        return { serverTopics };
    }
</script>
```

And then:

```
<script>
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
  export let topics = writable(serverTopics);
</script>
```

So basically, initialize the `topics` var with the preload value.

But in the markup:

```
{JSON.stringify(serverTopics)}
---
{JSON.stringify(topics)}
```

It shows data in `serverTopics` but `topics` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do:

```
{JSON.stringify($topics)}
```